# date-dependent automated tests in mainframe context

Tags: unit-testing, cobol, mainframe

As a former java guy with sound testing background, I am now in contact with mainframe / cobol stuff in the financial industry.

I want automated tests, but learned that it is really difficult to implement in our context so I ask here for advice.

1) My plan would be implementing a junit-based test-driver in java to call cobol stuff via stored-procedures, MQ or similar and to check the actual result in various DB2 tables. No problem here from MPOV.

2) The tricky thing is the context / data and here especially the date:

- Currently tests are done manually.
- The global "current date" is an
  important test-parameter and is set manually (and it affects a *lot*
  of other programs), so no one else may touch the system during such
  tests.
- Because tests are done manually, this lock of global context can easily be tracked:
  Mails like "do not touch anything on 12.12.2013, I am testing!"
- When tests are automated, this manual "single tester's global lock" approach is not possible anymore.

**=> How can we avoid this single locking? How can things like a global current date, or current exchange rates be easily synthesized?**

(current ideas are about cloning the whole context on a daily, weekly, monthly basis. This way one can still lock the given context. But I dislike the idea of "locking" or "owning" at all.)

Comment: Very interesting question, but not a good fit for the site. To avoid being stuck in the gut by "today's date", don't use it. Have a control file, which will contain all the dates in relation to the current data-day that you will ever need. Already coded up? Dumb as all heck, but very common dumbness. Separate LPAR for your testing, so no-one else is on it, you can toy with the date to your heart's content. For further, best to find a Mainframe forum, or one which specialises in you testing tool, rather than a Programming Q&A site, which is what this is.

Comment: On my linux box, I have written a .so that overrides the c library time(3) (and a few other) routines.  When I test, I preload that .so.  Nifty thing is that it affects only my process.  Perhaps there is sometime equivalent in your environment?

Comment: @ScottNelson, if the programmers were silly enough to use the clock date, they won't have done it in a way which is easily catered for. It'll be a mixture of COBOL, PL/I, Assembler under z/OS, SORT and any other way they can get hold of the date as lazily as possible. If you go low enough down to get everything, you get everyone, which OP wants to avoid.

Comment: The "don't use it" suggestion is appropriate for any system-level attribute. To use it without "using it", always access it through a wrapper procedure that supplies either actual system attribute or a test value, depending on some environment variable (or whatever) that you set. Of course, we can be sure that making an existing app work like that will take a **lot** of work since direct accesses will be coded everywhere.

Comment: So the advice from @BillWoodger is to make the current date configurable (I think it is already, because they manually test bankholidays, cut-off times and the like) and to supply separate "LPARS" for testing. IIUC, these are cloned partitions that behave exactly the same. OTOH, I expect setting these up will be bigger organizational task -> High costs. I'd love to see a pragmatic, low scale solution that I can implement in my project directly without having the environment changed substantially.

Comment: How is this solved elsewhere? The same problems must occur in every legacy cobol system with this kind of heavy-weight "global state" that affects testing.

Comment: On a Mainframe you can't just stop it and change the date if you have multiple systems running. Look at LPAR being Virtual Machine. The same problems do not occur in every legacy system, because not every system was written by nutters who used the machine date (I've never seen one, but I know from answering questions that many, at least now, do exist). ACCEPT date-field FROM CURRENT-DATE is a lunacy for anything with business logic. Typically Mainframe batch is overnight, so everyone knows two machine dates will be involved so everyone knows not to do it.

Comment: @user2338816 has it exactly. It is simple. If it has been done cheap-and-shoddy, then expenses for testing come with that package, errors for re-runs, parallel running would be a nightmare, even with your own LPAR, running multiple tests concurrently would not be possible, etc. Best is to design a "date file". Call it a Calendar, if you will. The first business processing of any given "day" is to update that file. Then the system uses that for all business-related date processing (of any date, because every date you need is there). Retrofitting not cheap, but you'll make savings.

Comment: By `system` I mean business system. All processing is on the Business/Data Date. Reports include the (Operating) System Date/Time, but simply so that a report can always be tied back to what produced it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trick thing with any automated unit testing -- even Junit testing.

The answer is you must pass in the dates.  Set up wrappers to "read current date and add it to the parameter list" for production, but have your unit tests call the modules that receive the date.

That is the only way to keep your tests from getting stale in any language or environment.

Comment: well done. sadly I learned in the meanwhile that mainframers will never refactor their code in such a way for such a ridiculous idea as automated testing ;-) risk is much too high to break something :-)